# SCSS custom responsive grid margin on last child issue

Tags: sass, grid-layout

I have created a basic grid system to replace bootstrap on my custom projects (trying to cut down on dependencies)

You can see the code here or below: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORVZyQ?editors=1100#0

The problem I am having is with the furthest right element having a margin.

The HTML in my code allows for 2x2 on a small screen and 4x1 on a larger screen, however, on the smaller screen, the second box is looped to the left as it has a margin.

How can I remove the margin if it is the last column.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="padding">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="background:#ff9900; height:20px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="background:#a82626; height:20px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="background:#ff9900; height:20px;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="background:#a82626; height:20px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
// Margin
$grid-spacing:3%;
$row-gap: 10px;

//Breakpoints
$xsmall: 480px;
$small:767px;
$medium:1024px;
$large:1600px;
$xlarge:1920px;

%clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:'';
}
.fullwidth {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    @extend %clearfix;
}
.padded {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    @extend %clearfix;
    @media screen and (max-width:$xsmall) {
        width: 100%
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:$xsmall + 1) and (max-width:$small) {
        width: $xsmall
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:$small + 1) and (max-width:$medium) {
        width: $small
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:$medium + 1) and (max-width:$large) {
        width: $medium
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:$large + 1) and (max-width:$xlarge) {
        width: $large
    }
    @media screen and (min-width:$xlarge + 1) {
        width: $xlarge
    }
}
.row {
    @extend %clearfix;

    & + & {
        margin-top: $row-gap;
    }
}
[class^="col-"] {
    float:left;
    margin-right:$grid-spacing;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 100%;
    &:last-child {
        margin-right:0%;
    }
}

.col-xs-1 { width: (100% - ($grid-spacing *11)) /12; }

.col-xs-2 { width: (100% / (12/2) ) - ($grid-spacing *10 /12); }

.col-xs-3 { width: (100% / (12/3) ) - ($grid-spacing *9 /12); }

.col-xs-4 { width: (100% / (12/4) ) - ($grid-spacing *8 /12); }

.col-xs-5 { width: (100% / (12/5) ) - ($grid-spacing *7 /12); }

.col-xs-6 { width: (100% / (12/6) ) - ($grid-spacing *6 /12); }

.col-xs-7 { width: (100% / (12/7) ) - ($grid-spacing *5 /12); }

.col-xs-8 { width: (100% / (12/8) ) - ($grid-spacing *4 /12); }

.col-xs-9 { width: (100% / (12/9) ) - ($grid-spacing *3 /12); }

.col-xs-10 { width: (100% / (12/10) ) - ($grid-spacing *2 /12); }

.col-xs-11 { width: (100% / (12/11) ) - ($grid-spacing *1 /12); }

.col-xs-12 { width: 100%; }

@media screen and (min-width:$xsmall + 1) {
    .col-sm-1 { width: (100% - ($grid-spacing *11)) /12; }

    .col-sm-2 { width: (100% / (12/2) ) - ($grid-spacing *10 /12); }

    .col-sm-3 { width: (100% / (12/3) ) - ($grid-spacing *9 /12); }

    .col-sm-4 { width: (100% / (12/4) ) - ($grid-spacing *8 /12); }

    .col-sm-5 { width: (100% / (12/5) ) - ($grid-spacing *7 /12); }

    .col-sm-6 { width: (100% / (12/6) ) - ($grid-spacing *6 /12); }

    .col-sm-7 { width: (100% / (12/7) ) - ($grid-spacing *5 /12); }

    .col-sm-8 { width: (100% / (12/8) ) - ($grid-spacing *4 /12); }

    .col-sm-9 { width: (100% / (12/9) ) - ($grid-spacing *3 /12); }

    .col-sm-10 { width: (100% / (12/10) ) - ($grid-spacing *2 /12); }

    .col-sm-11 { width: (100% / (12/11) ) - ($grid-spacing *1 /12); }

    .col-sm-12 { width: 100%; }
}
@media screen and (min-width:$small + 1) {
    .col-md-1 { width: (100% - ($grid-spacing *11)) /12; }

    .col-md-2 { width: (100% / (12/2) ) - ($grid-spacing *10 /12); }

    .col-md-3 { width: (100% / (12/3) ) - ($grid-spacing *9 /12); }

    .col-md-4 { width: (100% / (12/4) ) - ($grid-spacing *8 /12); }

    .col-md-5 { width: (100% / (12/5) ) - ($grid-spacing *7 /12); }

    .col-md-6 { width: (100% / (12/6) ) - ($grid-spacing *6 /12); }

    .col-md-7 { width: (100% / (12/7) ) - ($grid-spacing *5 /12); }

    .col-md-8 { width: (100% / (12/8) ) - ($grid-spacing *4 /12); }

    .col-md-9 { width: (100% / (12/9) ) - ($grid-spacing *3 /12); }

    .col-md-10 { width: (100% / (12/10) ) - ($grid-spacing *2 /12); }

    .col-md-11 { width: (100% / (12/11) ) - ($grid-spacing *1 /12); }

    .col-md-12 { width: 100%; }
}
@media screen and (min-width:$medium + 1) {
    .col-lg-1 { width: (100% - ($grid-spacing *11)) /12; }

    .col-lg-2 { width: (100% / (12/2) ) - ($grid-spacing *10 /12); }

    .col-lg-3 { width: (100% / (12/3) ) - ($grid-spacing *9 /12); }

    .col-lg-4 { width: (100% / (12/4) ) - ($grid-spacing *8 /12); }

    .col-lg-5 { width: (100% / (12/5) ) - ($grid-spacing *7 /12); }

    .col-lg-6 { width: (100% / (12/6) ) - ($grid-spacing *6 /12); }

    .col-lg-7 { width: (100% / (12/7) ) - ($grid-spacing *5 /12); }

    .col-lg-8 { width: (100% / (12/8) ) - ($grid-spacing *4 /12); }

    .col-lg-9 { width: (100% / (12/9) ) - ($grid-spacing *3 /12); }

    .col-lg-10 { width: (100% / (12/10) ) - ($grid-spacing *2 /12); }

    .col-lg-11 { width: (100% / (12/11) ) - ($grid-spacing *1 /12); }

    .col-lg-12 { width: 100%; }
}
@media screen and (min-width:$large + 1) {
    .col-xl-1 { width: (100% - ($grid-spacing *11)) /12; }

    .col-xl-2 { width: (100% / (12/2) ) - ($grid-spacing *10 /12); }

    .col-xl-3 { width: (100% / (12/3) ) - ($grid-spacing *9 /12); }

    .col-xl-4 { width: (100% / (12/4) ) - ($grid-spacing *8 /12); }

    .col-xl-5 { width: (100% / (12/5) ) - ($grid-spacing *7 /12); }

    .col-xl-6 { width: (100% / (12/6) ) - ($grid-spacing *6 /12); }

    .col-xl-7 { width: (100% / (12/7) ) - ($grid-spacing *5 /12); }

    .col-xl-8 { width: (100% / (12/8) ) - ($grid-spacing *4 /12); }

    .col-xl-9 { width: (100% / (12/9) ) - ($grid-spacing *3 /12); }

    .col-xl-10 { width: (100% / (12/10) ) - ($grid-spacing *2 /12); }

    .col-xl-11 { width: (100% / (12/11) ) - ($grid-spacing *1 /12); }

    .col-xl-12 { width: 100%; }
}
```

EDIT 1:
I have tried replacing the margin with padding, but this means that it doesn't go to the edge of the container: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkrroN?editors=1100#0

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, so you need to use with pseudo selector :nth-last-of-type instead of last-child

```
 [class^="col-"] {
    float:left;
    margin-right:$grid-spacing;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 100%;
    &:nth-last-of-type(1) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This means the same issue appears when you use :last-child

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that for smaller screens gonna be 2x2 you could do easily using the (even) rule and `&:last-child`

[Check on CodePen ( colors only for testing purposes )](http://codepen.io/TibicenasDesign/pen/JRYoQZ)

```
[class^="col-"] {
    float:left;
    margin-right:$grid-spacing;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;

    &:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: red;
      margin-right: 0;  
    }

    @media screen and (min-width:$small + 1) {
      &:nth-child(even) {
        margin-right: $grid-spacing;
      }

      &:last-child {
        background-color: blue;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
    } 
}
```

So now

```
1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - 6 and so on...
```

every even block gonna have margin-right: 0 but on bigger screens only the last one   ;)

TIP: Don't use units for zero values, is a bad practice

Comment: The smaller won't always be 2x2, this was just to show the issue really. It is a column based system like bootstrap, but just the grid part. I've looked at the bootstrap code, but I can't work out how it works. If the smaller is always 2x2, then yes, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I swapped out the margin for padding as per "EDIT1", but the reason for the space is i did not update teh grid width equations.

You need to remove the grid spacing portion. e.g.:

```
.col-md-3 { width: (100% / (12/3) ) - ($grid-spacing *9 /12); }
```

Changes to

```
.col-md-3 { width: (100% / (12/3) ); }
```